# Ionic 4 native storage - Error storing item Object code: 5, source: "Native", exception: null, stack:

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have this ionic 4 project (Using REST API) and have also install ionic native storage. I might have multiple questions concerning this project, but the first is:
I want to store login data so I can be able to pass a token to the header to be used for other endpoints. But if I run the app and try to login, I get the following error:

**Error storing item 
Object { code: 5, source: "Native", exception: null, stack: "" }**

My auth ts is where my login function is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  isLoggedIn = false;
  token: any;


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private api: ApiService,
    private storage: NativeStorage
  ) { }


  login(account_number: Number, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.api.API_URL + '/login',
      {account_number: account_number, password: password}
    ).pipe(
      tap(token => {
        this.storage.setItem('token', token)
        .then(
          () => {
            console.log('Token Stored', token);
          },
          error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
        );
        this.token = token;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        return token;
      }),
    );
  }


  register(name: String, email: String, phone: Number, reference: String, account_number: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.api.API_URL + '/register',
      { name: name, email: email, phone: phone, reference: reference, account_number: account_number, password: password }
    )
  }
  logout() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "auth-token" + this.token
    });
    return this.http.get(this.api.API_URL + '/logout', { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(data => {
          this.storage.remove("token");
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
          delete this.token;
          return data;
        })
      )
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.storage.getItem('token').then(
      data => {
        this.token = data;
        if (this.token != null) {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.token = null;
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And here is is my login.ts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/services/alert.service';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register.page';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  userdata: any;


  constructor(
    private modalC: ModalController,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertService: AlertService,
   // private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    // Dismiss Login Modal
    dismissLogin() {
      this.modalC.dismiss();
    }
    // On Register button tap, dismiss login modal and open register modal
    async registerModal() {
      this.dismissLogin();
      const registerModal = await this.modalC.create({
        component: RegisterPage
      });
      return await registerModal.present();
    }
    login(form: NgForm) {
      this.authService.login(form.value.account_number, form.value.password).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.userdata = data;

          this.alertService.presentToast("Logged In");
          console.log('this is loggin in userdata', data, "and this is the stored auth-token", this.userdata.message);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error, "logged in");
        },
        () => {
          this.dismissLogin();
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/dashboard');
          console.log('this is this.userdata', )
        }
      );
    }

}
```

Here is aslo my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy,  } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,],
  entryComponents: [

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    NativeStorage,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use javascript local storage and also use Ionic native storge for your purpose.

Mostly is used localStorage.set(). In case just want to store strings.

u also use Ionic native storage for the object and many things.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage

Comment: Can you please check my code and see if I miss anything?
I don't know if the error is from ionic storage or npm

Comment: You use native storage only store token?

Comment: If yes. then use this.
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
localStorage.getItem('token')
just simple. No longer need to b complex.